# How to submit form on enter without submit button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I want to submit my form on enter without adding button inside an Antd form. Is there any way to do this in React?

I think about workaround to just hide button, but don't think this will be the best way to do it.

Comment: In which field you want to press enter there attach an onKeyup event and the keycode like `event.keyCode === 13` (for enter I believe) then submit the form.

BTW, please share what did you try.

Comment: Please provide your Antd form sample code that you tried

Answer (score 3):

1. store **ref** of the antd Form inside your component(for accessing to **submit method**)
2. add `onKeyUp` to Form
3. you need to add `tabIndex={0}` to Form if you want to onKeyUp work on entire Form and not just inputs
4. enter keyCode is 13 so you need to handleKeyUp like this:

```js
const SimpleForm = () => {
  const ref = useRef();

  function handleKeyUp(event) {
    // Enter
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      ref.current.submit();
    }
  }

  return (
    <Form ref={ref} onKeyUp={handleKeyUp} tabIndex={0}>
      <Form.Item
        label="Username"
        name="username"
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: "Please input your username!"
          }
        ]}
      >
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>

      <Form.Item
        label="Password"
        name="password"
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: "Please input your password!"
          }
        ]}
      >
        <Input.Password />
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};
```

or you can listen to keyup event on **window** like this:

```
const SimpleForm = () => {
 const ref = useRef();
  function handleKeyUp(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      ref.current.submit();
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("keyup", handleKeyUp);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keyup", handleKeyUp);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <Form ref={ref}>
    .
    .
    .

  );
};
```

Comment: It works, but The form refreshed the whole page.

Answer (score 3):

`onSubmit` is not available in antd v4. Use `onKeyPress` instead.

```
<Form
  form={form}
  onFinish={console.log}
  onKeyPress={(e) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      form.submit();
    }
  }}
>
    //
</Form>
```

Comment: OnKeyPress is deprecated.

Comment: What's the alternate @blockhead? although I couldn't find onKeyPress in the documentation but seems to be working as expected

Comment: @BlackMamba you can use keydown https://stackoverflow.com/a/69826211/6499765

Comment: Got it thanks @blockhead would continue with onKeyPress until it works 

Answer (score 0):

```
submitFunction=(event)=>{
console.log('form submitted.')

}
```

**in render func**:

```
 < form onSubmit={this.submitFunction}>
   // input...
 < /form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it work with Antd this [example](https://ant.design/components/form/) in reference docs should work.

Since you mentioned React, the code below should submit the form on pressing `enter`. The trick is to add onSubmit property to the form tag.

```
export default class Module extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {}
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);

  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //your code
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        //form code
      </form>
    );
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use onSubmit event handler! if you don't want a button to submit the form. for example

**The Submit Function**

```
handleSubmit(e){
e.preventDefault()
// your form submission logic
}
```

**Use onSubmit on form**

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export default class Module extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {}
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //your code
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        //form code
        // Hide this button using CSS
       <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
```

May be this'll work. By default **submit** button inside catches **enter** key press so you don't have to do any radical thing just put a **submit** button inside form and hide that button, on enter key it'll automatically submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the onKeyUp props in your input

```js
const handleSubmit = () => {
// function body for submitting data
}

<input
  onKeyUp={(ev) => {
              if (ev.keyCode === 13) {
                handleSubmit();
              }
            }}
/>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your snippet has errors.